# split city and county from the adres with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this:

```
some address number city / state
```

I want to split this string into a list like this:

```
[some adress number, city, state]
```

How can I make it with python?

Comment: If it has no proper delimiters or a structure it is impossible to do it reliably then NLTK would be the way to go.

Comment: @VineethSai I have loaded from excel into dataframe and want to seperate that, I couldnt find solution, so, best way to make it with excel.

Comment: Post a sample of lines of your dataframe or excel. Then maybe someone can help you. Right now your question is incomplete in many ways.

Comment: There is'nt any standart, line on question is the best standard right now. I will delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that some address number is of variable length. so you could try this.

```
s='some address number city / state'
lst=list(s.split())
print(lst)
print(lst.index('/'))
addr=' '.join(lst[:lst.index('/')-1])
lst=lst[lst.index('/')-1:]
print(lst)
lst.insert(0,addr)
lst.remove('/')
print(lst)
```

Let me know in case you have any doubts